# Number of Solutions of Discrete Logarithm Problem in modular field

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

Consider the equation

$$
a ^ x \equiv b \mod p
$$

where $p$ is a prime number, and $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}_p^{\times}$. According to e.g. https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiscreteLogarithm.html, there exists exactly one solution $x \in \{0, \dots, p - 2\}$ if $a$ is a primitive root of $p$.

But what if $a$ is *not* a primitive root of $p$? How many solutions $x \in \{0, \dots, p - 2\}$ exist?

For example, if $a = 1$, then the equation has $p - 1$ solutions $x \in \{0, \dots, p - 2\}$ if $b = 1$ and no solutions otherwise.

If $b = 1$, then $x$ is a solution iff $a ^ x \equiv 1$, i.e. iff $\mathrm{ord}(a) | x$.

How could I proceed in the general case?

Comment: I think the general case would be very wierd and is a lot dependent on $b$.

Answer (score 1):

- multiplicative inverses have same order (because multiplicative inverse of 1 is 1)
- additive inverses have same order if order of -1 is even, but half or double order if not.
- you could use factorization to do more.
- you could also use that $$y=mx+b\land p\mid m\implies y^p\equiv b^p\pmod{pm}$$

Or just explore (in PARI/GP) with :

```
forprime(p=3,500,for(a=1,p-1,print1(znorder(Mod(a,p))","));print())
```